# Creating new form in Magento 2 always getting error

Tags: magento2, adminform, fatal-error

I have created a custom module, it has a grid and also should have an add new button, the grid is working but the add new button is giving me errors. Below is given **NewAction.php** inside **Vendor_Module_Controller_Adminhtml_Index**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class NewAction extends \Module\Vendor\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
{
    /**
     * Create new customer action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
        $resultForward->forward('edit');
        return $resultForward;
    }
}
```

So now, it will load the Edit, because I will use, edit file to edit or add new.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * Customer edit action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

And this is the error getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Interceptor::getMainTable() in /var/www/html/site/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/Collection/AbstractCollection.php:145 Stack trace: #0
```

Comment: please give edit action code you are using.

Comment: public function execute()
    {

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        return $resultPage;
    }